# I am looking for a recent four part set of articles on Casper

Tags: casper

Can somebody give me links to the recent articles on the history and design of casper?  I saw a part 3 and a part 4, but don't recall who wrote them and I want to start with part 1 and part 2.

Answer (score 1):

The author is Vlad Zamfir.

Here are parts 1 and 2 (others can be easily found).

https://medium.com/@Vlad_Zamfir/the-history-of-casper-part-1-59233819c9a9
https://medium.com/@Vlad_Zamfir/the-history-of-casper-chapter-2-8e09b9d3b780